# Do off axis sources produces the same diffraction pattern as on axis sources?

Tags: optics, diffraction

Let's say I have a simple lens and I am viewing two sources of light A and B through this lens. A is on the axis and B is not as shown in the digram below. Will A and B produce exactly the same diffraction pattern (given that they are of the same dimension etc.)? (Also assume that we are in viewing it in the image plane and hence we have Fraunhofer diffraction).  [image]

My guess at an answer would be that they are slightly different because the beam width on the image side of the lens is different. So for the object on the axis we have fringe spacing of the order of $\frac{\lambda}{W}$ where $W$ is the width of the lens. But in the second case (off-axis object) we would have a diffraction pattern with spacing of the order of $\frac{\lambda}{W \cos{\theta}}$ where $\theta$ is the angle made to the principal axis by the of axis beam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a paraxial thin-lens approximation, two otherwise identical beams from two different (but paraxial) directions produce the same image (but displaced inside the image plane). You can see this by tilting your setup such that first one and then the other source is on-axis: For a thin lense, this process only introduces changes that scale with $1 / \cos \theta \approx 1 + \theta^2 \approx 1$ for sufficiently small angles $\theta$.

Comment: Hi many tanks for your answer, is my equation with $1/cos(\theta))$ right then?

Comment: Yes. In fact, it seems you must be using the same argument, so it is correct within exactly the same caveats. Instead of "spacing" for your diffraction pattern, "width" (of the zeroth maximum) seems more natural to me, but if your object/image is not something that will not have higher diffraction orders (such as a Gaussian intensity pattern), both will work.